# Hide all absolute positioned elements

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to make all the elements that are in the absolute position become hide?

```
 $("#element").hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate all items and to verify if the element has absolute position:

```
$("*").each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("position") === "absolute") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XDkr/)

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can use the attribute selector with contains clause `*`

```
$('[style*="position: absolute"]').hide()
```

**Edit**

This will hide only if the element has inline style for position.

Or you can use the code below to hide all the elements using `filter()`

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('position') == 'absolute';
}).hide();
```